# convert text to single type

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, font-size

```
        Dim fontsize As Single = CSng(SynopsisTSCmbFontSize.Text)
        rtbSynopsis.Font = New Font(SynopsisTSCmbFonts.Text, fontsize)
```

to change the fontsize to the value selected in a combo box, the value has to be of the Single type.

the combobox is populated with numbers entered at the design mode, ranging from 7-78.  I know that these are entered as strings.

the error is :

[image]

I have tried a number of things to convert the text (which are numbers, no letters) from the combobox to single to no avail.  try parse did not work, trimming did not work, first convert to INT or DBL, then to SNG did not work.

What is the correct syntax here?

I would have thought that it was pretty standard stuff to change the fontsize.

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem here. Do you have text representing a floating point number there? In what format? Can you show what is the input you're parsing? Possibly, also specify the current culture's decimal separator (if there's one, that is).

Comment: What message do you get when you run the code? Have you tried hard coding the value of the font size?

Comment: I have updated my question.  I don't know how else to pose the question.  How do you get from text in combobox to a single type value?

Comment: You didn't specify what is the input you're parsing. What is the content of `SynopsisTSCmbFontSize.Text` the moment you pass it to `CSng()`? Have you debugged this code? If you didn't, then do it now.

Comment: *"try parse did not work"*. Then you did it wrong. If only there was a way for us to know what you did so we could work out what's wrong with it. I'm guessing that you ignored whether or not it was actually successful and just went ahead and used the data anyway, which would defeat the whole purpose. Of course, we wouldn't have to guess if you showed us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution : instead of populating the combobox at design time, I populated it at runtime where I had full control over the type.

```
    Dim i As Single
    For i = 5 To 70
        SynopsisTSCmbFontSize.Items.Add(i)
        TreatmentTSCmbFontSize.Items.Add(i)
    Next
```

once the comboboxes are correctly populated, I can run the rest of the code with no errors

thank you all for your time!